# SVN: forcing theirs-full

Tags: svn, conflict

I have an svn local copy. I changed some files. Usually after `svn checkout ...` I got conflict message with options what to do with changed (in local copy) files. One of that option was `theirs-full`.

But this time after `svn checkout` I got G status on those files and no conflict message.

How can I get the server copy of those files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subversion only gives the conflict options (like `theirs-full`) if there is a conflict in the file: a change on the server that it can't merge into your local version.  In your second case, Subversion was able to merge your local changes and the server changes without any problems, so it didn't need your input on what to do.  If you want the server version, you can use `svn revert` to overwrite your local copy or `svn cat` to show the server copy or save it into a different file.

Comment: 1) How can I make svn not to be able to merge, so I get conflict options? (I have access to both server and local copies, also I know what was changed in files) 2) I want to overwrite only some files. Is it possible with `svn revert`?

Comment: You can revert individual files (and requiring them to be named explicitly is the default for `svn revert`).  I do not know how to force a conflict; does it make sense in your application to overwrite the local copies every time?  I believe (but am not sure) that marking a file as binary prevents merging (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.file-portability.html#svn.advanced.props.special.mime-type).

Comment: `does it make sense in your application to overwrite the local copies every time?` — Do you mean overwrite with svn or manualy? I change local files in testing/debugging purposes, its rare cases. In my first question I meant following: I know what parts of code were changed. Can I put some tricky stuff there so that svn was unable to merge?

Comment: @SaltLake -- I mean with SVN on every `svn update`.  If you know what was changed, you could just do `svn revert` manually before (or after) you update.  Or are you concerned about forgetting to do that and leaving your changes around or committing them?

Comment: @Jeremiah Willcock Thanks a lot! Problem solved with `svn status` + `svn revert`.

Comment: @SaltLake: you can force SVN to generate conflicts by configuring it to [use and external merge tool](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html) which always report a failure to merge, e.g. a batch file which simply returns an error code.